# How will the Windows8Challenge prizes be awarded?

Tags: support, windows-8-challenge

I <s>read</s> skimmed through the Windows8Challenge site and can't find any information how how/when the prizes will be awarded. Will winners be contacted to get the necessary information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the contest rules:

**Contacting the winners**

- We will attempt to contact the winners by using the email addresses on their user accounts. If the user does not reply to us within four weeks, we will award the prize to the user who asked the next highest-voted question or answer (or most viewed question, as applicable).

Comment: Oops. Didn't really notice that button. Thanks.